# Solidity Shared Pool

Tags: addresses

I am trying to build and deploy my first solidity contract. I have no experience in web development and come from a python / data science background.

My goal was to do something simple and see how I can interact with it / test it in real life.

I want to build an option for 2 users to get "married" and as such share a common pool of ETH. The ultimate goal would be for each user to be able to use this pool directly (just like shared accounts at the bank).

What I have below seems to work fine in testing (if you have any comments on improvement and security issues I would gladly take them) but I can't find a way to stack ETH somewhere.

Sure, I could replace the "increase balance" function with a transfer but to which address?

Hope you can help me with this beginner problem. If you have any advice for the deployment of the code and how I would interact with / test it on the main network, again, I would gladly take your comments.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.18;

contract marriage {

  address owner = msg.sender;
  int val;
  mapping (address => uint256) private current_balance; // store the current personnal balance
  mapping (address => address) private link;           // store the 2 addresses
  mapping (address => uint256) private state;          // state : 0 = awaiting nothing, 1 = awaiting partner approval, 2 = married
  mapping (address => uint256) private shared_balance;

  function check_personnal_balance () public returns (uint256)
  {
    return current_balance[owner];  // the associated value in the mapping of the address, owner here
  }

  function increase_balance (uint256 incre) public {

    require(owner == msg.sender);

    current_balance[owner]=current_balance[owner]+incre;
  }

  function decrease_balance (uint256 incre) public {

    require(owner == msg.sender);

    current_balance[owner]=current_balance[owner]-incre;
  }

  function view_my_address () public returns (address){

    require(owner == msg.sender);

    return msg.sender;
  }

  function view_my_state () public returns (uint){

    require(owner == msg.sender);

    return state[owner];
  }

  function get_partner_address () private returns (address){  // a function to return owner's partner

    require(owner == msg.sender);

    return link[owner];
  }

  function check_partner_link ()  private returns(address)  {  // a fucntion to check which address partner is linked to

    require(owner == msg.sender);

    address current_partner;

    current_partner = get_partner_address();
    return link[current_partner];
  }

  function reset_state () public {  // a function to reset states

    require(owner == msg.sender);
    

    address current_partner;

    // split funds here
    current_partner = get_partner_address();

    state[current_partner]=0;
    state[owner] =0;
    link[current_partner]=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000;
    link[owner]=0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000;

  }

  function request_partner (address _partner) public{ // a function to request a new partner
    require(owner == msg.sender);
    state[owner]=1;
    link[owner]=_partner;

    if (check_partner_link() == owner) {    // check if partner also requested a state to owner, if so marry 
      state[owner]=2;
      state[_partner]=2;
    }
  }

  function add_to_shared_balance (uint amount) public {

    require(owner == msg.sender);
    require(state[owner]==2);
    require(current_balance[owner]>=amount);  //needs enough personnal founds

    shared_balance[owner]=shared_balance[owner]+amount;     //increment shared balance
    current_balance[owner]=current_balance[owner]-amount;   //substract personnal balance
    
    //match partner's shared balance with owner's
    address current_partner;
    current_partner = get_partner_address();
    shared_balance[current_partner]=shared_balance[owner];
  }

  function remove_to_shared_balance (uint amount) public {

    require(owner == msg.sender);
    require(state[owner]==2);
    require(shared_balance[owner]>=amount);     //needs enough shared founds

    shared_balance[owner]=shared_balance[owner]-amount;   //increment personnal balance
    current_balance[owner]=current_balance[owner]+amount; //substract shared balance

    address current_partner;
    current_partner = get_partner_address();
    shared_balance[current_partner]=shared_balance[owner];
  }

  function check_shared_balance()public returns (uint){

    require(msg.sender==owner);

    return shared_balance[owner];
  }

}
```

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Firstly owner should be set within the constructor.

Secondly instead of having the same require in every function, you should create a modifier onlyOwner and add it to each function. It will greatly improve readability.

Thirdly instead of having your mappings private and having a getter function for each of them, you could simply set them as public.

Fourth Im not really sure how you imagined the architecture to look like, but currently the contract only supports one married couple. This means you don't really need the 4 mappings, but could use simple variables instead.

Fifth I noticed you don't really implement any ether transfers. To do so, your function should be set as payable, and in the function, you should use msg.value to see how much ether is being passed. Then you can use address(this).balance to fetch the current contract balance.

There are also other options to optimize the code, especially to reduce the contract size, but these should help you achieve your goal.